# upgrade vb.net 2005 to 2008 and now debug will not work

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I've upgraded a windows form app from vb.net 2005 to 2008.  I've gone into the project and told the debug to point to bin\Debug and active to point to bin\Release.  Now when i change the mode to active, it puts the files in the release folder.  when i change it to debug, the files are not put into the debug folder.  I think it is putting them in the release.  If that is the worst that happens ok. but the problem is when i put it to debug and run it, i get a message

Microsoft Visual Studio
The following module was built eitheer with optimizatons enabled or without debug information.  C:....\Quicke Db Tools.exe

To bebug this module, change the projet build configuartion to Debug mode.

I've got it changed to debug mode, but it's like it not taking it... how do i get it working again.
thanks
shannon

Answer (score 0):

Set the current configuration to Debug in the toolbar, not in Project Properties.

The dropdown list in Project Properties doesn't actually set the current configuration; it just lets you change settings in other configurations.

You need to set the active configuration using the dropdown list **in the toolbar on top**.

Answer (score 0):

well.. i should have posted this question a while ago.. because no sooner then i do and i got it working.  i needed to right click on the solution and go to the configuration manager.  i toggled active from release to debug to release and debug from debug to release to debug.  rebuilt the solution and bam.. it's all working now.

thanks
shannon